# Why is my message handler running even when it is not defined in WebAPI?

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I have the following set-up in my config:

```
routes.MapHttpRoute("NoAuthRequiredApi", "api/auth/", new { id = RouteParameter.Optional } );
routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApi", "api/{controller}/{id}", new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }, null, new WebApiAuthenticationHandler());
```

If I post anything to the url on **api/auth** the message handler still runs and checks for an Auth-Token header.  Is there any reason why this is happening?  Is there something I should change in the configuration of the WebApi routes? I obviously don't want any auth token on the header when making requests to the auth controller because at that point I'm trying to retrieve the token for use on other controllers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your topmost route is never being matched as there is no indication of which controller is required. Add the controller name in as a default. (And remove the ID optional if this is not required).

So:

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "NoAuthRequiredApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/auth/",
        defaults: new { Controller = "Auth" }
    );
```

Comment: Still getting this error: POST http://localhost:49597/api/auth/1 401 (Unauthorized) with your change.

Comment: @jaffa, if you include the id "/1" you need to add it to the route template /api/{id} otherwise it will continue to fail to match. I don't know why you would want ID in the route though.

Comment: Hi, I got it working. I thought it wasn't working because I was getting a 401, but it turned it was explicitly raising that in the auth controller so it was getting further along.